# How does the Beer-Lambert law arise from a collection of dipoles?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

The Beer-Lambert law says that one solution to the macroscopic Maxwell’s equations is one which demonstrates an exponential decay of light intensity in the direction of incidence. Consider a polarizable dielectric material. Can someone help explain how the Beer-Lambert Law arises due to interference between the incident light and the electromagnetic radiation sourced by the induced dipoles in the material? Thanks!

Comment: *The Beer-Lambert law says that one solution to the macroscopic Maxwell’s equations is one which demonstrates an exponential decay of light intensity in the direction of incidence.* According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer–Lambert_law), “The Beer–Lambert law is not compatible with Maxwell's equations.”

Comment: I believe Wikipedia is saying that using the Beer-Lambert law combined with the notion that all light that is not reflected or transmitted is absorbed is faulty. However if we use the Beer Lambert law simply to describe absorption within a homogeneous medium then Maxwell's equations should be compatible.